# FileChooser to select a directory, not a file

Tags: windows, pywin32, filechooser

My code processes all the files in a folder on a Windows box. I want to offer the user (who happens to also be me) the option to select the folder to be processed, using the standard File Chooser dialog.

I am trying to use the [GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927(VS.85).aspx) function to make this happen. (I am actually calling it from Python via [pywin32](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32gui__GetOpenFileNameW_meth.html), but that shouldn't be relevant.)

I can get it to select a particular file, but I can't see any options to let the user select a folder instead.

Is there a flag combination I haven't understood, am I calling the wrong function entirely or is there another idiom for doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you're calling the wrong function entirely. It's been a while since I've done Win32 gui stuff.. but I seem to recall that there was a different way of bringing up a "select directory" box. It wasn't a straight Win32 function, but was some shell API function that required a whole heap of code to do the simplest thing.

Update: A bit of google reveals the [SHBrowseForFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762115(VS.85).aspx) function.

Update two: And here is an [example for Python](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/browse-for-a-folder.html).

Answer (score 2):

As Greg mentions, the function you want is a shell function. The specific function you need is [`SHBrowseForFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453669.aspx), which is pretty messy to call. There's also [PyWin32 documentation for it](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/shell__SHBrowseForFolder_meth.html) which mentions the `browse_for_folder.py` sample.